# Figures exceeding bottom page limits on MDPI Latex Template

Tags: graphics, margins

I'm facing a problem on MDPI latex template: the image is exceeding bottom margin.

Example:
[image: Example]

Code fragment:

```
\end{paracol}
\nointerlineskip
\begin{figure}[H]
    \widefigure
    \includegraphics[width=15 cm]{Definitions/logo-mdpi.eps}
    \caption{Foo Foo Fooo Foooooooo.}
    \label{fig:Foooo}
\end{figure}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\linenumbers
\switchcolumn
```

I'm using the default mdpi definitions of overleaf template. I've only added two more packages: subcaption and siunitx.

Comment: The issue is not replicable with that fragment of code, however, I would try replacing the `[H]` in your `figure` by a lowercase h, so `[h]`. If that is not enough, you could use `[!h]`, but always lowercase h